# Filezilla external ip mismatch error

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I was trying to connect to my server using filezilla today and got the following errors:

```
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
```

an on the configuration wizard i get this:

```
Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Response: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.10.2
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
Retrieving external IP address from http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 141.105.80.1 beb-baf-ia-b
Response: 510 Mismatch. Your IP is 212.28.232.2, cbc-ci-cdc-c
Wrong external IP address
Connection closed
```

I tried setting filezilla to get my external ip from their server abd my computer none worked
Oh and it was working last night

Comment: if you need any additional information please just tell me

Comment: This is usually a problem with NAT routers, passive vs. active mode and maybe also servers behind a firewall or router. More debgging help can only be done if you describe your network setup (client, server, router, firewalls, public vs. private IP addresses etc) and debug messages from the client. But there are actually lots of similar questions at stackoverflow.com or serverfault.com so you might try to look there first if they already help with your problem.

Comment: Please include FileZilla log. For a start, read my article about [problems with FTP and network configuration](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).